# Correct Privileges in Amazon S3 Bucket Policy for AWS PHP SDK use

Tags: amazon-web-services, laravel-4, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-php-sdk

I have server S3 buckets belonging to different clients. I am using AWS SDK for PHP in my application to upload photos to the S3 bucket. I am using the AWS SDK for Laravel 4 to be exact but I don't think the issue is with this specific implementation.

The problem is unless I give the AWS user my server is using the FullS3Access it will not upload photos to the bucket. It will say Access Denied! I have tried first with only giving full access to the bucket in question, then I realized I should add the ability to list all buckets because that is probably what the SDK tries to do to confirm the credentials but still no luck.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::clientbucket"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

It is a big security concern for me that this application has access to all S3 buckets to work.

Comment: The PHP SDK just sends the requests signed with the credentials you give it. If you are getting access denied errors, then it is a permissions problem, and has nothing to do with the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Jeremy is right, it's permissions-related and not specific to the SDK, so far as I can see here. You should certainly be able to scope your IAM policy down to just what you need here -- we limit access to buckets by varying degrees often, and it's just an issue of getting the policy right.

You may want to try using the [AWS Policy Simulator](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UsingPolicySimulatorGuide/using-iam-policy-simulator.html) from within your account. (That link will take you to an overview, the simulator itself is [here](https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/home/index.jsp?#).) The [policy generator](http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html) is also helpful a lot of the time.

As for the specific policy above, I think you can drop the second statement and merge with the last one (the one that is scoped to your specific bucket) may benefit from some * statements since that may be what's causing the issue:

```
"Action": [
    "s3:Delete*",
    "s3:Get*",
    "s3:List*",
    "s3:Put*"
]
```

That basically gives super powers to this account, but only for the one bucket.

I would also recommend creating an IAM server role if you're using a dedicated instance for this application/client. That will make things even easier in the future.